# How to change line spread of minipage in tabular for a consistent line separation?

Tags: tabularx, minipage

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\linespread{1.5}\selectfont%\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.62}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{lc}
      row 1 &
      \begin{minipage}{18em}
        %\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}\selectfont
        \linespread{1.2}\selectfont
        minipage with long content: blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah ...
      \end{minipage} \\
                row 2 &
      just one line\\
      row 3 &
      \begin{minipage}[t]{18em}
        \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.2}\selectfont
         minipage with short content
      \end{minipage}\\
                row 4 &
      just one line\\

    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

As you can see, the separation between row 1 and row 2 is obviously smaller than that of row 3 and row 4. 
[image: MWE result]

Comment: can't you use a `p` column rather than minipages?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I tried. But I cannot change line spread then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the outstanding abilities of TeX is that you can have nested environments. If you need different line spread inside a tabular environment, use a spacing env.

I used some different ways to play with vertical skips, as you can see in my example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcounter{rowc}
\setcounter{rowc}{0}
\newcommand{\rowno}{\stepcounter{rowc}row \therowc}

\begin{document}
This is a tabular with different line spreads:

\bigskip{}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{m{2cm}m{10cm}}
  \rowno{} &
             \begin{spacing}{.9}
               \blindtext
             \end{spacing}\\[-5ex]

  \rowno{} & just a one liner \\
  \rowno{} & short content, but more than one line, just to see the vertical
             spaces\\
  \rowno{} & And the last line.
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image: tabular with different line spread]